# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'language_id' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In an attempt to make a Java servlet to implement add functionality, the following error shows up in the console of Eclipse:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'language_id' cannot be null

Written below is my attempt of preparing the PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO film (title,release_year,special_features,rating,description,language_id)"  +
        " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT language_id FROM `language` WHERE `name`=?));");
        
ps.setString(1,titleValue);  
ps.setString(2,releaseYearValue); 
ps.setString(3,specialFeaturesValue);
ps.setString(4,ratingsValue);
ps.setString(5,descriptionValue);
ps.setString(6,languageValue);

int i = ps.executeUpdate();
```

The table structure in MySQL DB is as follows:

`FILM TABLE -> title | description | special_features | release_year | rating | language_id`

`LANGUAGE TABLE -> language_id | name`

The `language_id` of `FILM` table is the foreign key of the `language_id` primary column of `LANGUAGE` table

Comment: Are you sure the value you are setting with `ps.setString(6, languageValue)` exists in the column `name` of `LANGUAGE` table?

Comment: @AlfredoTostón I wish I could share a screenshot of the `SELECT * FROM LANGUAGE` output. It has 3 columns, language_id, name and last_update columns

Comment: Try to debug your app in order to know whats exactly the value of variable `languageValue` when you bind it to the prepared statement. Then execute with a database client `SELECT language_id FROM language WHERE name = '<the value you just got>'` and see if this value exists in the database. You are probably passing a wrong value to the query.

Comment: What is the DDL or your table?

Comment: @AlfredoTostón my bad, I passed language as parameter in the api url instead of addLanguage, and hence languageValue was getting null value :(